# How can I achieve a completely custom tab bar in react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

**Explanation**

I want to create a completely custom tab bar that looks like this:

[image]

I know that `react-navigation` `createBottomTabNavigator` component can take this option `tabBarComponent`

So if I create a completely custom component it has a background color and also it's attached to the bottom. So if I move my component up a bit, it indeed does but it also expands from the bottom. As you can see here:

[image]

(The red border is my custom component with a marginBottom, but as you can see it's still attached to the bottom, so I thought maybe make the backgroundColor transparent but that does nothing. Here is how I tried it:

```
{
    tabBarComponent: TabBar,
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#4F4F4F',
      inactiveTintColor: '#ddd',
      style: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      },
    },
  },
```

**What is the best way to achieve this? Do I even need TabNavigator or maybe another navigator? How can I set the background color to transparent?**

Answer (score 0):

You can have elevated buttons with images. To have images for each tab you need to provide a custom icon to tabBarIcon prop (which can be any component), I just  created basic components button1, button2, button3 in my example.

I just added a bottom style prop to elevate the buttons, but since it's a completely custom component, there should be more than one way to do it.

```js
    const TabBarNavigation = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Tab.Navigator
                  screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
                    tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
                        if (route.name === '1') return button1();
                        if (route.name === '2') return button2();
                        return button3();;
                    },
                  })}
                  tabBarOptions={{
                    showLabel: false
                  }}>
            <Tab.Screen name={'1'} component={FirstScene} />
            <Tab.Screen name={'2'} component={SecondScene} />
            <Tab.Screen name={'3'} component={ThirdScene} />
          </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    };

    const button1 = () => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.highButton}>
              <Image source={require("../assets/icons/image1.png")}/>
            </View>
        );
    }

    const button2 = () => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.highButton}>
              <Image source={require("../assets/icons/image2.png")}/>
            </View>
        );
    }

    const button3 = () => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.highButton}>
              <Image source={require("../assets/icons/image3.png")}/>
            </View>
        );
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        highButton: {
            bottom: '50%'
        }
    });
```